# How to setup midi input?

Tags: keyboard, input, midi, rosegarden

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and want to setup a M-Audio Axiom 49.

I have tried to read up on jackd1 / jackdmp /jackd2 / qjackctl and whatnot, but haven't gotten any sound from the keyboard yet.

A long time ago i managed to get sound from it using rosegarden and qjackctl, but not anymore.

I have timidity installed and can play midi audio with it.

In rosegarden there are no available midi input devices when the keyboard is plugged in and turned on.

In qjackctls connections window in the midi tab there are no "readable clients", even when running vkeybd and zynaddsubfx and having my keyboard plugged in.

From lsusb i can see:

```
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0763:0199 Midiman Axiom 49

From cat /proc/asound/cards:
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xfbf20000 irq 93
 1 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xfbe40000 irq 94
```

What do I need to do to get audio from my keyboard?

tags += jackd, timidity (website wouldnt let me add those)

Answer (score 1):

I apologize at the outset for just providing a partial answer, but I can at least tell you that I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with an Axiom 49 successfully "out of the box" (no special configuration necessary). The output to lsusb looks the same for me as for you, so I don't think the problem is there.

I'm using python with pygame to read in MIDI events. (if you are interested I could post some sample code, but you'd have to install pygame to use it)

I am guessing the issue is somewhere in JACK or Rosegarden, though I don't use those so I can't help with them. Hopefully constraining the search to those components rather than Ubuntu itself is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've never had any trouble using my MIDI drumkit in Ubuntu. I select the MIDI input in the application itself (hydrogen, whose configuration dialogue lets me choose my M-Audio Delta 1010LT as the MIDI source). In this set-up I don't think I've ever seen qjackctl report the card as a readable client, so I guess what you are seeing is normal. If the applications you are trying to route MIDI to let you configure the MIDI source within themselves, try using that.

Comment: I tested hydrogen and it doesnt list the midi keyboard as a midi source.